# Unpacking error within numerical integration in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

Here is my code snippet to draw an integral function by `NumPy`, `SciPy` and `MatPlotLib` libraries:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sigma = 1

def integrand(x,n):
    return (n/(2*sigma*np.sqrt(np.pi)))*np.exp(-(n**2*x**2)/(4*sigma**2))

tt = np.linspace(0, 20, 0.01)
nn = np.linspace(1, 100, 1)

T = np.zeros_like([len(tt), len(nn)])

for i,t in enumerate(tt):
    for j,n in enumerate(nn):
        T[i,j] = quad(integrand, -oo, t, args = (x))

plt.pcolormesh(tt,nn,T)
```

But there is a `ValueError` as below about a `unpacking`-related issue:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Python Tools for Visual Studio\2.1\visualstudio_py_util.py", line 106, in exec_file    exec_code(code, file, global_variables)
  File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Python Tools for Visual Studio\2.1\visualstudio_py_util.py", line 82, in exec_code     exec(code_obj, global_variables)
      File "C:\Users\Matinking\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\NeuroSimulation\NeuroSimulation\XSundry\test2.py", line 63, in <module>
plt.pcolormesh(tt,nn,T)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2946, in pcolormesh
ret = ax.pcolormesh(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.py", line 7747, in pcolormesh
X, Y, C = self._pcolorargs('pcolormesh', *args, allmatch=allmatch)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.py", line 7357, in _pcolorargs
numRows, numCols = C.shape
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
Press any key to continue . . .
```

The issue is seemingly related to the last line of the code, but I can'y figure any solution out for that...

Could you please enlightening me upon this case?

Kind regards

Comment: The loop varibakes are floating point numbers. You are using "t" and "n" which are not indexing variable

Comment: You want to say something like: "for i, t in enumerate(TT)" and similarly for your other variable.

Comment: @Sandman: That might be.. But as I am a new comer in this territory, I would be grateful if you let me know about the potential solution... I mean, how should i use `i` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sigma = 1

def integrand(x, n):
    return (n/(2*sigma*np.sqrt(np.pi)))*np.exp(-(n**2*x**2)/(4*sigma**2))

tt = np.linspace(0, 19, 20)  # divides range 0 to 19 into 20 equal size portions. Thus, tt = [0, 1, 2, ..., 19]
nn = np.linspace(1, 100, 100)  # nn = [1, 2, ..., 100]

T = np.zeros([len(tt), len(nn)])

for i,t in enumerate(tt):
    for j,n in enumerate(nn):
        T[i, j], _ = quad(integrand, -np.inf, t, args=(n,))  # evaluate integral from -infinity to t, with value of n in the function set to n passed in from here.

x, y = np.mgrid[0:20:1, 1:101:1]  # create a mesh/grid for plotting.

plt.pcolormesh(x, y, T)  #plot

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you, but The `ValueError` does still exist and nothing has been changed in view of the result...

Comment: Your integrand function is defined to take 2 arguments, but is only provided one. is "n" the second argument you want to provide since I don't see you using that inside the loop anywhere?

Comment: You're right... `n` must be taken as the other argument into account... How would the code supposed to be, then?...

Comment: args=(x, n) in the quad function call. Though I am not sure where you are getting the value of the variable "x" in your code.

Comment: I don't think so... `args` tuple is the representative of the integration variable, is which `x`... `args=(x,n)` transforms the 1-D integral to a 2-D one...

Comment: Look at the code I have posted. This works and produces a colormesh.

Comment: I would truly appreciate for your kindness to let me have an error-free version of the code. Although its output plot is not as desired as it supposed to be (in comparison with the `Matlab` version), but now I can trace the semantic of the code and improve it, efficiently....

Comment: That depends on the parameters over which the Matlab script is integrating. Make sure that the values of "tt" and "nn" match up with the values in the matlab script you have. You may want to use http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html instead of np.linspace since from your original code you seem to be providing a step value instead of number of intervals between a range.